# Data inserted double time on key press event of edittext in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am calling method of db helper while user press done/next/enter, button but that code is executed twice and data entered twice in table.

Here is my key press event of edit text:

```
editTextLitre.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch(keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        TextView txtlitres = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_litre);
                        TextView totalamount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.amount);

                        RadioButton rbBuffalo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBuffalo);

                        RadioButton rbCow = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioCow);
                        rbBuffalo.setText(Constants.Buffalo.toString());
                        rbCow.setText(Constants.Cow.toString());
                        radioanimal= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioCategory);
                        int selectedid = radioanimal.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedid);


                        DBHelper dh=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        boolean save = dh.insertMilkDetails(mandali,rb.getText().toString(),totalamount.getText().toString(),txtlitres.getText().toString(),dt.toString(),session.toString());

                        if(save == true)
                        {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I can't understand why data is inserted twice in database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    editTextLitre.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        TextView txtlitres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_litre);
                        TextView totalamount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);

                        RadioButton rbBuffalo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBuffalo);

                        RadioButton rbCow = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioCow);
                        rbBuffalo.setText(Constants.Buffalo.toString());
                        rbCow.setText(Constants.Cow.toString());
                        radioanimal = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioCategory);
                        int selectedid = radioanimal.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedid);


                        DBHelper dh = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        boolean save = dh.insertMilkDetails(mandali, rb.getText().toString(), totalamount.getText().toString(), txtlitres.getText().toString(), dt.toString(), session.toString());

                        if (save == true) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Details Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

What I changed :   `if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { ...`

Because an `onKey` event happens twice when you press a key: Once when you press, once when you release the key.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, key events are generated for every action during a key press (i.e key down AND key up).  Your code checks for the key code type, but does not validate whether the event was `ACTION_DOWN` or `ACTION_UP`.

The `KeyEvent` object passed in provides you this information ([see docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)); you likely only want to do the insert on the up action.

Another, probably better, option since you are using `EditText` is an `OnEditorActionListener` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)), which doesn't require you to check such things.